# Android image view makes the app slow

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, imageview, base64

In my app i have an `ImageView`. Before adding that `ImageView` the app was performing smooth. now *it throws ANR*.

The image is saved in the database as  base 64 encode string and it is decoded to bitmap and loaded to the imageview using :

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

The conversion of `bitmap` and applying the `bitmap` to `ImageView` all those things are done in an `AsyncTask`:

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private String data = "";

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView, String data) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        this.data = data;
    }


    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length, options);

        return decodedByte;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `AsyncTask` is called from the main ui using the following code:

```
BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(pollWebView,decodedStrings[1]);
                task.execute();
```

decodedStrings[1] contains the base64 encoded image dataUrl.

Any solutions for this problem?

Comment: What is the size of the bitmap?

Comment: it can vary from 10 kb to 10 mb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major issue which is letting your app slow is WeakReference remove it and try whithout that

don't use this

```
 private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
```

just use

```
private final ImageView imageViewReference;
```

Comment: what is the reason behind that?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html

look at this and accept the answer it this works.

Comment: i have only 9 reputation, for upvote i need 15. so i cant do that. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to compress image (**75%** compression)

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
       String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```